# File exist in PHP with japanese character

Tags: php, file-exists

I have a file in あ.gif under images folder.
Now I want to check file exist or not but the japanese character was not accepting and it return output as false, But there is a file in あ.gif

Here is my code...

```
$path    = $WRITING_IMG_PATH;
$file    = "あ.gif";
$fullfilename =$path.$file;
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo $file;
} else {
    echo "No file";
}
```

In my code it returns false, if there is file in that images folder.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $fullfilename` just to be sure it is the right path?

Comment: Ya of course It will show the correct file path but the file_exists function always return bool(false) for japanese character file name.

Comment: Output like this　../../sjla/webroot/upload/writing/縺�No file　　　　　Antonis Tsimourtos

Comment: This depends on what character encoding the underlying file system uses, and what character encoding your saved your script in - if those don’t match, then you are comparing different byte sequences that only _look_ the same to you in the respective systems you are viewing them in. Use `glob`, `scandir` or sth. like that to get all the folder entries, and then see what byte values this file name actually contains at that position.

Comment: Windows or Linux? If Windows, I'm afraid that your options are kind of limited since PHP does not make use of the appropriate libraries to handle Unicode file names.

Comment: I am using Windows. Here I got a alternate solution $files=file_get_contents($path);                                                                if (strpos($files,$char) !== false) {
   echo "true";
   } else {
    echo "fail";
   }

Comment: @PaulCrovella OMG, that's awesome!!